Movie/TV show with soldiers defending mine from aliens
It was way before year 2000 when I saw it. 
I remember it in glimpse and I think that they were soldiers defending some mine from aliens. That company hired soldiers on an alien planet, I think they were mind controlled by some chemical or implants. 
They were fighting some other race but you can sense through whole movie that something is wrong. 
In the very end you see alien race that are also mind controlled to see "good" guys as aliens as well while actually they are all humans that just kill other humans. 
I was reminded of it while I watched Black Mirror season 3 (Men Against Fire). Similar story is in 5th Wave and Ender's Game. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

@ajem Please add the language you saw it in. I would assume the language was English but please confirm. It is obvious the genre is sci-fi.

I'm pretty sure you are looking for Outer Limits (1995-2002) Season 4, Episode 3: Hearts and Minds (1998). All the elements you describe fit the plot clues you give. The "aliens" are actually opposing sides of humans who are drugged so that they see the opposing side as "despicable" aliens. 
IMDb storyline:

A military squad led by Capt. Tavernier and Lt. Rosen patrol a complex series of caves on an alien planet. They're there to protect a key mineral - now used on Earth to provide power - from invading bug-like creatures. The aliens aren't only dangerous they are deadly requiring the team to regularly inoculate themselves against infection. When they learn that Rosen has not been receiving her injections due to a malfunction, Tavernier makes it clear she'll be on her own at the first sign of infection. Their immediate concern is to take control of a processing plant that the bugs will shortly make operational. As her medication wears off, Rosen begins to see things in a different light.

YouTube:




You are my hero, thanx a lot, thats it
